# How to find multiples of 3 and 5, push to an array, and then sum the array

Tags: ruby

I am trying to sum the multiples of 3 and 5 that are less than 1000 using `each`, and then `push` to store them all in array `multiples`. I am trying to learn how to use these commands, and so I don't want to use `select` and `inject`.

I have controllers set up to print `@your_output` on another page, and have done this successfully with simpler problems. I tried to do the conditional and store it in `div`:

```
def third_program
  numbers = (1..999).to_a
  multiples = []
  numbers.each do |num|
    div = num % 3 == 0 || num % 5 == 0
    multiples.push(div)
  end
  @your_output = div.sum
  render("programs_templates/third_program.html.erb")
end
```

With this code I get an error.

Here is the solution that worked for me:

```
def third_program
    numbers = (1..999).to_a

    # Your code goes below.
    multiples = []

    numbers.each do |num|

      if num % 3 == 0 || num % 5 == 0
          multiples.push(num)
      end
      end
    @your_output = multiples.sum

    render("programs_templates/third_program.html.erb")
  end
```

Comment: what error did you get

Comment: I think you need to define div outside of the each loop

Comment: What is `render`?

Comment: Try `1000.times.inject(0) { |m,a| m += a if (a%3 == 0 || a%5 == 0); m }`

Comment: If you solved the problem in the question, please turn that into a self-answer using the form below.

Answer (score 0):

An easier way to do it would be as follows...

```
multiples.push(div) if num % 3 == 0 or num % 5 == 0
```

Answer (score 0):

You have a couple of problems.
First you are trying to access `div` outside the `each` block.
If you really wanted to do that,  which you don't because you should be calling `sum` on `multiples`, not `div`, you would need to define it at the method scope level and then allow the `each` block to modify it.

Second you should be pushing `num` not `div` to `multiples`.

Thirdly you need to check if `div` is true before you push to the array.

I have not checked the rest of your logic,  so there might be other bugs as well.

```
   def third_program
        numbers = (1..999).to_a

        # Your code goes below.
        multiples = []
        numbers.each do |num|
          div = num % 3 == 0 || num % 5 == 0
            multiples.push(num) if div 
        end
        @your_output = multiples.sum

        puts @your_output
    end
    third_program
    # => 233168
```

Comment: As mentioned in another answer you don't need to convert the range to an array, but it does not break your program,  and yes,  you can simplify things farther, for example removing the div variable and having it all on one line, but if you like having the div line for readability there is nothing wrong with that either.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add `num` to `multiples` if `num` is both divisible by `5` and `3`, not `div`. That's because `div = num % 3 == 0 || num % 5 == 0` is just `true` or `false`, adding div ends up with an array of booleans values (`[false, true, true, ...]`).

`@your_output = div.sum` is outside the loop and div does not exist there, it's out of the scope.

Even if in scope, you are calling `@your_output = true.sum` (or `false.sum`) getting an error anyway: `NoMethodError`.

The variable `div` is actually not required, use just its condition. Also it's not necessary to convert the `Range` into an `Array`. So, I'd suggest this refactor:

```
def third_program
  multiples = []
  (1..999).each do |num|
    multiples << num if num % 3 == 0 || num % 5 == 0
  end
  @your_output = multiples.sum

  # render("programs_templates/third_program.html.erb")
end

p third_program #=> 233168
```

This can be further shortened:

```
@your_output = (1..999).select{ |n| n % 3 == 0 || n % 5 == 0 }.sum #=> 233168
```

Comment: I improved the explanation